# firefox addon, hide javascript source

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, obfuscation

Can someone tell me which tools/methods you use to obfuscate the javascript code when you create your addon/s?

We have a problem of another DEV messing with our code, creating some other crap with it and then bad mouthing us :(
(seriously, how low can some people stoop?)

I understand it wont keep truly determined souls at bay, but we want to atleast make him work for it before he gets the source. Frustrate the bugger for a while at least ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript

Comment: @trutheality, I did google and find that, and tried some of those out but they seem to throw some errors when I try to use FF addon code there...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish your addon in addons.mozilla.org I think that you must not use obfuscated javascript.

You can try to contact someone from Mozilla about your problem and if the problem is really serious they can blacklist the other add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links you may find useful:

1. http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com
2. http://javascriptcompressor.com/
3. http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptDemo/UnescapeEncoderDecode.htm
4. http://jscompress.com/
5. http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html

But you know, one click encrypt = one click decrypt :(

Comment: Thats ok, as long as it makes it harder for him to get everything he is looking for. Will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed in Firefox-specific JavaScript, but it should be possible to run it through a JavaScript minifier like http://jscompress.com/ to obfuscate your code.